# Managing error messages generated by Postgres \copy command

Tags: database, postgresql, shell

I am working on a tool to import large sets of files into a Postgres database. Currently I have a working prototype - a bash script going over the list of files, and using `psql` with the `\copy` command to import each file.

I would like to add some error handling; I'm thinking of parsing error messages to generate feedback for users, but I can't find a specification, or a list of error messages that are generated by the `\copy` command in particular.

Is there a tool, or a library, or even a reference list that I could use? I am constrained to use either Shell or Node with the Postgres module.

Answer (score 0):

That should be fairly simple; just check the return code:

```bash
psql -c "\copy ${atable} FROM '${afile}' (FORMAT 'csv')"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "copy failed!"
fi
```